# I need an easy, secure multi-file upload on a dreamhost website

Tags: web

Any suggestions? My goals are the following:

- works in as many browsers as possible (so as few dependencies as possible)
- allows easily uploading multiple files
- secure

Thank you very much. I know a little JavaScript, but the part where I am faltering a bit is the PHP to actually handle the upload. I've found some scripts, but all say that security is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a secure upload, you'll need SSL.  With Dreamhost, you'll have to pay for a unique IP address.  Dreamhost also sells a certificate, not sure if you can provide your own.  Check the [Dreamhost control panel](https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=domain.secure) for details.

If you want to store the files on disk, you'll want to provide encryption.  I'm sure that there are many options to choose from (for example [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)).